# How to use delegate function with multiple params in c#

Tags: c#

I have delegate function which is :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void AddMultiInformation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str, 
                                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str2,
                                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str3);
```

I use this delegate function in a callback for C DllImported function as below.

```
[DllImport("CarsDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
internal static extern int GetCarsInformations(AddMultiInformation carsData);
```

Which type of parameters that I can use to call GetCarsInformations function correctly please ?

```
class Program
{
    // Constructor
    protected Program()
    {
    }

    // Main
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        //GetCarsInformations();
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the signature of your delegate

```
public delegate void AddMultiInformation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str, 
                                         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str2,
                                         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str3);
```

you'd need a method that

- Returns `void`
- Has exactly three arguments which are all `string`.

So, something like

```
public void MethodThatAddsMultiInformation(string str, string str2, string str3)
{
    // put some logic in here
}
```

You'd then be able create an instance of the `AddMultiInformation` delegate by assigning it a reference to the `MethodThatAddsMultiInformation` method:

```
AddMultiInformation addMultiInformation = MethodThatAddsMultiInformation;
```

and then call `GetCarsInformations` with the instance of the delegate:

```
var information = GetCarsInformations(addMultiInformation);
```